# Userform Combobox caluculation not calculating correctly

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a problem with my math or code which is causing the calculation to of the combobox values be inaccurate. Where the sum should be 100% I am getting either 80% or 125%. 
There are 11 comboboxes which can be 1-5 or NA. NA has a value of 0.
Here is the code I am using:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim c As Control, n1 As Long, n2 As Long, n3 As Long, n4 As Long, n5 As Long
n1 = 0
n2 = 0
n3 = 0
n4 = 0
n5 = 0

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        If c.Value = "1" Then n1 = n1 + 1
        If c.Value = "2" Then n2 = n2 + 2
        If c.Value = "3" Then n3 = n3 + 3
        If c.Value = "4" Then n4 = n4 + 4
        If c.Value = "5" Then n5 = n5 + 5
    End If
Next c

TXTCount = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5)

For Each c In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(c) = "ComboBox" Then
        If c.Value = "1" Then n1 = n1 + 1
        If c.Value = "2" Then n2 = n2 + 1
        If c.Value = "3" Then n3 = n3 + 1
        If c.Value = "4" Then n4 = n4 + 1
        If c.Value = "5" Then n5 = n5 + 1
    End If
Next c

TXTPotential = (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5 * 4)

TXTScore = TXTCount.Value / TXTPotential.Value
```

(The results can be over 100% with more 4 and 5 scores given)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is an order of operations issue.

Try `TXTPotential = ((n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5) * 4)`

edit:
I changed some of your variable names and removed n1, n2, etc, you can leave them in if you are doing something with each one individually but in this code chunk it is not necessary to have so many.

```
    Dim target_control As Control
    Dim control_value As Integer
    Dim control_count As Integer


    control_value = 0
    control_count = 0

    For Each target_control In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(target_control) = "ComboBox" Then
            If Not target_control.Value = "NA" Then
                control_value = control_value + cint(target_control.Value)
                control_count = control_count + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next

    TXTPotential = control_count * 4 'I'm guessing

    TXTScore = control_value / TXTPotential
```

edit 2:

this should disregard 0s

Comment: When I do that I get .20 or 5

Comment: What are your actual numbers here? Is the potential value the number of comboboxes * 3?

Comment: I am summing the responses in the 11 comboboxes (answers are 1-5, NA=0) Example 9 responses with a 4 and 2 NA's would = 36. (TXTCount)
Then I count the number of responses (1-5) and multiply that by 4. In this case would also be 36. (TXTPotential).
Then Divide the Count /Potential to get the score.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be what you're doing in this code. The first part will get you the 36, however, the second part has no reset on the variables so you will be at 72 but you are multiplying n5 * 4 in this example that would be 0 so you should get 36/72. Where does the 4 come from if these are test scores or something similar you want to take a count of your combo boxes (11) and multiply that by the base score (i'm guessing it is 3) and put the txtcount over that so 36/33.

Comment: These are performance review results. In some of the reviews some of the categories may not apply which is why we have the NA option. It does not hurt or add to their review. So I am not sure how to make it not multiply the n5*4 but instead by the entire sum of n1-n5

Comment: Oh i misread your second loop, it won't be 72 but it will still be off.

Comment: Warcupine! You are amazing! This solved the issue. Thank you for sticking with me through this who confusing mess!